# Populating Ionic select with Data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I want to populate my select tool with data which I am calling from a service.
I am still new to `Angularjs` so this is a little difficult to figure out. If someone can refer an article or a piece of coding for me I would appreciate it.

NOTE: I am not trying to get an easy answer, I have searched Google but can't find anything relevant to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: figure what out? You haven't identified a specific problem or shown any code

Comment: It is not an error or something I have, it is just a lack of knowledge on how I should do it. @charlietfl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML define select tag with model and ng-options:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
<select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="item.name for item in items">    
</select>
```

In your controller initialize items for your select:

```
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

$http.get('your/api/that/returns/json/').then(function(result){
 $scope.items = result.data;
})

    });
```

For further details please read this excellent article: [A Brief Walk-through of the Ng-options in AngularJS](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/)